# FPDF - Only output file to server

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I try to save the output of my generated file on my server.

The Code:

```
$pdf->Output('pdfs/'.$order.'.pdf', 'F');
header("Location: ../email.php");
```

But when I open the php file in my browser, it still shows the php file with my pdf reader..
Why doesn't this just save the file and redirect me to the email.php?

Comment: You need to `exit()` after the `header()`

Comment: @Pekka웃 I tried it with exit(header("Location: ../email.php")); and exit(); after the header. both doesn't work :/

Comment: It may not be the solution to your problem, but a `header(Location:)` always requires an `exit()` afterwards. Could the problem be that `$pdf->Output` doesn't actually write its stuff out into a file?

Comment: I have the informations from here: http://blog.startq.com/index.php/2011/10/25/fpdf-output-methods-for-pdf-files-in-php/

Comment: That looks ok then. Not sure what's happening here then, have you reloaded your page and cleared the cache to make super sure there's nothing stuck somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with incognito modus and tried it with an other browser too.

Comment: Then you're going to have to do further debugging and find out what goes wrong - is it the `Output()` call that outputs the stuff? Then something's wrong with either the library or the documentation.

Comment: I have found the solution. There was this line a bit above: $ezs->createEinzahlungsschein(false, true);  The first "false" stands for showing the pdf or not ;) Thank you for your help :)